# Heroku - Uninitialized constant Nameerror for existing Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4

Spent a bunch of time trying to find a solution to this answer, but to no avail.

Heroku gives me an error when trying to deploy. For whatever reason, it gives me a "uninitialized constant V1::BaseController (NameError)" when I try including my actions controller. It works locally, yet fails to push to heroku. All the other controllers with the same lines work when I remove the action controller both locally and on heroku.

Here's the specific error from heroku:

```
2014-01-17T08:53:46.149322+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-01-17T08:53:46.149322+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/V1/actions_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant V1::BaseController (NameError)
2014-01-17T08:53:46.149322+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
```

actions_controller.rb

```
class V1::ActionsController < V1::BaseController
```

sessions_controller.rb (deploys and works correctly when actions_controller.rb is commented out)

```
class V1::SessionsController < V1::BaseController
```

base_controller.rb

```
class V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
   ...
end
```

I've checked my models to see if there were any mistakes there. Anyone got any suggestions on how to fix/debug? Thanks.

**Update:**

I solved my issue by changing the name of ActionsController to LogsController. It seemed to be some sort of naming issue and that BaseController needs to always be loaded first alphabetically.

Comment: It seems that the `ActionsController` is loaded before `BaseController`, easily you can avoid it with the mixins, which you can store into library as modules

Comment: Thanks for the insight @majioa. I spent some time looking for more info but to no avail. Could you possibly point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Are you striktly need the `V1` namespace? It could be really confusive for rails.